# How to have Menu like apycom

Tags: routes, theming, javascript

How can I create menus like [Apycom Menus](http://www.apycom.menu) ?

Do I need to create custom module and then use it which will be available to whole site or I can just use css and js from the apycom menus?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code, you can integrate it with your Drupal's templates. Otherwise, I don't see how you could do it.

Comment: I have the js and css files. But the issue is menu id to be created dynamically and then using css and js on that list items has to applied. A module would be needed which will create menu from database. Is there any other solution apart from this?